How to perform a derivative on a sign function?
I have $$\phi = \phi(x,y) = sgn(y)\arccos\bigg(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\bigg)$$ and I want to perform the derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$. I know what to do for arccos, but not sure what to do for the sign function; what is the process for taking this derivative?

Working through to where I get stuck:
$$\frac{\phi}{sgn(y)} = \arccos\bigg(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\bigg)$$
$$\cos\bigg(\frac{\phi}{sgn(y)}\bigg) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
replace $\frac{\phi}{sgn(y)}$ with $\frac{f(\phi(x,y))}{g(y)}$ just to make the notation more general and I think easier to follow:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \Big(\frac{f(\phi(x,y))}{g(y)}\Big) = -\frac{\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}x}{x^2+y^2}$$
$$\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}g(y) - \frac{d g}{d y}f(\phi(x,y))}{g(y)^2} = -\frac{x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{-\frac{x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}g(y)^2 + \frac{d g}{d y}f(\phi(x,y))}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}g(y)} = \frac{-\frac{x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}g(y) + \frac{d \ln(g)}{d y}f(\phi(x,y))}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}}$$
And subbing back in from our previous step:
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} = -\frac{x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}sgn(y) + \frac{d \ln(sgn(y))}{d y}$$
So where I left off was evaluating $\frac{d \ln(sgn(y))}{d y}$, or $\frac{1}{sgn(y)}\frac{d sgn(y)}{d y}$. How would I evaluate this derivative?

split into cases and accept the fact that it doesn't exist on $(x,y), y=0$. You could consider the weak derivative however this is somewhat beyond the question

Since $$ \operatorname { sgn } y = \cases { 1 &for $ y > 0 $\\ - 1 &for $ y < 0 $,} $$ it's mostly constant.  The derivative is $$ \frac { \mathrm d ( \operatorname { sgn } y ) } { \mathrm d y } = \cases { 0 &for $ y > 0 $\\ 0 &for $ y < 0 $.} $$  Sometimes people leave $ \operatorname { sgn } 0 $ undefined like I did, and sometimes people define it to be $ 0 $, but in any case, the function's not differentiable at $ 0 $.  So as long as you keep in mind that the derivative doesn't exist at $ y = 0 $, you can just take $ \mathrm d ( \operatorname { sgn } y ) / \mathrm d y $ to be $ 0 $.  (And your formula for $ \phi $ doesn't really work at $ y = 0 $ anyway.)
You can also do the $ y > 0 $ and $ y < 0 $ cases separately.  Replace $ \operatorname { sgn } y $ with $ 1 $ and see what you get; then go back and replace it with $ - 1 $ and see what you get.  Then you never have to think about $ \operatorname { sgn } y $ when doing the calculation, at the cost of doing it twice.
By the way, if you want to avoid imaginary values, then when you replace $ \tfrac { \mathrm d g / \mathrm d y } g $ with $ \mathrm d ( \ln g ) / \mathrm d y $, you should really replace it with $ \mathrm d ( \ln | g | ) / \mathrm d y $, in case $ g $ might be negative (which is kind of the point of $ g $ when $ g $ is $ \operatorname { sgn } y $).  But now you know that this is $ 0 $ anyway.
